# Are there free wake word engines for use with the Alexa Voice Service?

Tags: alexa

The [AVS Sample App](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-avs-sample-app) is great to play with on a Raspberry Pi as a cheaper, more home-made version of Alexa. However, both the wake word engines ([TrulyHandsfree](https://github.com/Sensory/alexa-rpi) and [Kitt.AI](https://github.com/Kitt-AI/snowboy)) have problematic licenses.

By **free**, I'm looking for an engine where both the code and the training data provided is licensed for use for both personal and commercial uses. The TrulyHandsfree engine has a [very restrictive license](https://github.com/Sensory/alexa-rpi/blob/master/LICENSE.txt) permitting personal use only, and the binaries they provide *stop working entirely* after about 3 months to try and discourage unlicensed use. The Kitt.AI engine is slightly better, but their [webpage](https://snowboy.kitt.ai/) specifically says that the "Hacker" pricing (their free tier) does **not** have a commercial license.

**Does Amazon provide a more free wake word engine, or are there any engines that support the AVS sample with less restrictive licensing?**

Comment: You could look into the [Mycroft](https://mycroft.ai/) project to see what they do.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Porcupine](https://github.com/Picovoice/porcupine)?
It's a pretty well maintained open source project and has an Apache 2.0 license.

Answer (score 1):

HomeAssistant now includes an entirely open source voice assistant toolchain.

- [OpenWakeWord](https://github.com/dscripka/openWakeWord) is the open source wakeword engine; it's licensed under the Apache 2.0 license.
- [faster-whisper](https://github.com/SYSTRAN/faster-whisper) is the open source speech-to-text engine; it's licensed under the MIT license.
- [Piper](https://github.com/rhasspy/piper) is the open source text-to-speech engine; it's also MIT licensed.

You should be able to use any or all of these projects.  HA supports a myriad of languages, but I'm not sure where the training data is.